# CSS properties definition overwrites Knockout js css binding

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I've noticed that if you define a `<style>` tag in your markup, like this:

```
 tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:#F4F4F4;}
```

And then you try to apply a css binding using knockout (this sets a background-color when you click on a row):

```
<tr data-bind="click: $parent.selectRow, css: {red:  $parent.seletedRow() == $data}">
```

The second one is not set since I already defined a background-color within the  `<style>` tag.

I need to mark the even rows with a color but when you click over a row its background-color must be replaced by the css class `red`. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/q3Uuz/1/ Try to click on the second row and you notice the `red`class is not applyed.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there is no need for using `!important;`

A more specific selector than your `tr:nth-child(even)` also fixes your issue

So you can write something like:

```
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#F4F4F4; }

tr.red { background-color: red; }
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xFxvG/)

You can read more about how the [selector's specificity calculated](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `!important` to `background-color` style in red class:

```
.red {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3Uuz/2/

Comment: there is no need for `!important;` a more specific selector also fixes it like:  `tr.red {
       background-color: red;
    }`

Comment: every time when you use `!important`, one little koala is crying because this is no more cascade style sheet.

Comment: Agree with you guys, never again :)

Comment: @nemesv please post this comment as answer.